# Jquery code does not execute when input still focused

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The submit button of my form is disabled by default and gets enabled when the phone number entered is correct (ie: when the div underneath says: "OK").

So I wrote this:

```
  $(document).on('change', 'input', function() {
    if ( document.getElementById('phone-number-validator').innerText === 'OK') {
      $('.btn-default').prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
```

The thing is, the button gets enabled only when the phone number input is unfocused. So the problem is: if the user press 'enter' after he/she filled the phone number input, or click on the submit button while the input still focused, it won't submit the form as the submit button is still disabled.

To enable the button, the user must click at least once outside the input.

I would like to change my code so that the user can submit the form even though the focus is still on the phone number input. Is there a way to do so ?

Comment: can you please post relevant html code also so that you can help you in better way

Comment: Try like this `$('.btn-default').removeAttr('disabled');`

Comment: you should try `keyup` event instead of `change`

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for your help. The `$('.btn-default').removeAttr('disabled');` do not change the problem; the use of `keyup` actually solves it. I'll validate the answer asap @BhushanKawadkar

Comment: @JulesCorb, sure. Also, you can use jquery to ready text of phone validator element instead of `document.getElement...` which will reduce you code

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar thank you for the suggestion. I actually have to add more fields in the future to the form so I think It should be better to listen to the document :)

Comment: @JulesCorb, even if you add more elements to the form you have to ensure that id of each elements must be unique so that you will not get any trouble while dealing with html elements. offcourse, it is your choice to go with jquery or document.getElementById. Good luck!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change event will be triggered only after focus out but you can use keyup or keydown event handlers to validate and enable submit button

```
 $(document).on('keyup', 'input', function() {
    if ( $('#phone-number-validator').text() === 'OK') {
      $('.btn-default').removeProp('disabled');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `jQuery keyup` event for this:

```
 $(document).on('keyup', 'input', function() {
    if ( document.getElementById('phone-number-validator').innerText === 'OK') {
      $('.btn-default').prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
```